# How to use paranoia gem in many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the followings models:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid
  has_and_belongs_to_many :fiscals, uniq: true
end

class Fiscal < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid    
  has_and_belongs_to_many :client_suppliers
end
```

I run a migration to put deleted_at field on two tables and the join table, but when I destroy the client the deleted_at in join table it not updated.
What can I do to update that field?

Answer (score 1):

the first thing that you should do is make sure that your models have a `deleted_at` as a `date_time` and make it a index so it can find those records easier

```
class AddDeletedAtToModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :models, :deleted_at, :datetime
    add_index :models, :deleted_at
  end
end
```

in your model all you have to do is:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
  ...
end
```

to find records that are deleted all you have to do is:

`Model.with_deleted`

I hope that this helps

Comment: But the has_and_belongs_to_many association has a join table that needs to be deactivated to. I think that just put acts_as_paranoid in the models of the join table will not deactivated the join table.

Comment: it should if the `deleted_at` flag has a value it should ignore the record like it does not exist