# Soft Delete has_and_belongs_to_many association using discard gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, soft-delete

What is the best way to soft delete **has_and_belongs_to_many** associations using **Discard** Gem.
With this association, there is a join table in database but without actual Ruby on Rails Model.

I'll try to explain via an example, lets say there are 2 models:

```
class Participant < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :company_employees
end


class CompanyEmployee < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :participants
end
```

> This will create company_employees_participants middle/join table in database BUT without any model in Ruby on Rails. Where i can make settings for discard gem ?

Any idea how i can solve this requirement where we need to have soft delete in joined tables using has_and_belongs_to_many assocaition in discard gem ?

discard gem: https://github.com/jhawthorn/discard

I'm using 
**ruby 2.5.3, Rails 5.1.6, discard(1.0.0)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any gem that can soft delete a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. The best way forward would probably be to refactor your relationship and make it explicit with `has_many :through`. This allows you to customize the relationship, e.g. with soft delete. The change is pretty straightforward:

1. Create a migration to rename the join table.
2. Create a new model and match the name of the table.
3. Change `has_and_belongs_to_many` to `has_many :through`.

You can then go ahead and follow discard's instructions to enable soft delete.

Generally speaking, I would avoid `has_and_belongs_to_many` as much as possible. Sooner or later, I've always had to customize the join model and had to refactor the code. `has_many :through` is just slightly more work to set up initially, but it's so much more flexible down the road that it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [paranoia](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia) gem. This gem helps you to implement the soft delete functionality. If you don't want to use the gem then you can implement it manually.

If you want to integrate manually the changes are simple:

- First, you need to add migration to add the column `deleted_at` as a `datetime` data field type.
- Then you can write scope to filter out the data the same as `paranoia` gem do e.g. `with_deleted` where you can check the `deleted_at IS NULL`
- Whenever you delete any record you can set the `deleted_at`.

I found one reference on StackOverflow you can refer it [How to use paranoia gem in many to many association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188533/how-to-use-paranoia-gem-in-many-to-many-association/41188873)

hope it will help you